# Django User form empty with forms.ModelForm

Tags: python, django, modelform

I'm trying to create a form with only some fields to modify from the django user model, but when i try this code:

```
class UserEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
class meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name',]
```

and i do:

```
user_db = User.objects.get(pk=u_id)
user_form = UserEditForm(instance=user_db)
```

i get an empty form.
Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your whole views.py?  Seems like it's coming from there. That you're missing something in your view.

Comment: Is this what your code looks like verbatim? That line should be `class Meta:`, not `class meta:`.

Comment: Yes.. the error is the "class Meta:".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks

The error is:

```
class Meta:
```

with capital letter.

Thank you!